# Expand pandas column list of string values into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data in dataframe, the second column is a list of string:

[image: i have data in data frame]

The desired outcome would have two separate columns for `content.images...`:

[image: The desired outcome would be]

Comment: There are many existing duplicates, search for *\[pandas\] expand column into multiple columns*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this example input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['X', 'Y'],
                   'col2': [['ABC', 'DEF'],['GHI', 'JLK', 'MNO']]})

#   col1             col2
# 0    X       [ABC, DEF]
# 1    Y  [GHI, JLK, MNO]
```

You could `apply(pd.Series)` and add a custom prefix with `add_prefix` before doing a `join` with the original dataframe:

```
out = (df.drop(columns=['col2'])
         .join(df['col2'].apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('col2_'))
         .fillna('') # optional
      )
```

output:

```
  col1 col2_0 col2_1 col2_2
0    X    ABC    DEF       
1    Y    GHI    JLK    MNO
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
df[['content.images.0','content.images.1']] = df['content.images'].str.split(', ', expand=True)
```

Comment: in my case this work, thank you
df[['content.images.0','content.images.1']] = list(df['content.images'])